# Why React Native's setstate replace array's elements with one element only?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, state

I have an issue with React Native.

If I set a new value for an element in an array, the array is no longer shown, only 'X' appears in its place.

```
export default function App() {

  var [arr, setArr] = useState(["s","e","r","k","l","p","f","t","h"])

  function set(){
    setArr(arr[1]="X")
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{arr}</Text>  
        <Button title="click" onPress={set}/>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />      
    </View>
  );
}
```

Why is this, and what can I do to make it update just the one element?

Comment: Can you separate JS from React and be a little more specific?

Comment: change `setArr(arr[1]="X")` to `const newArr = [...arr]; newArr[1] = "X"; setArr(newArr);`. What is happening here is that `setArr` expects a complete replacement of the state, and you are only supplying  a single value. It is also not a good idea to mutate state, as React works on reference comparisons and might not detect changes in state as intended if you do.

Comment: The `useState` updater function completely replaces the state object, so if there is any state you want persisted you ***must*** shallow copy it yourself. In other words, copy the current state array ***then*** update the value at a specific index.

Comment: @JacobSmit thanks for the help, was the answer that i need